# What happens if you destroy a Dungeon chest that hasn't generated loot?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

1) What happens if a Dungeon chest that hasn't had its loot generated gets destroyed?

2) Assuming it can be picked up, once it's placed again, would it still try to generate loot, or would it become a normal chest?

[image: The offending chest]

Comment: I haven't yet destroyed it.

Comment: Allow me to say... WAT?

Comment: Uhh, last I checked the items spawn in the chests as soon as the chests are rendered.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you interact with the chest (opening, breaking, using a hopper to insert/remove items, using a comparator to get signal strength, or using a dropper to insert items), it will generate the loot and allow interaction (which answers the second question as the chest broken will just be a normal chest and the loot will drop on the ground).

Comment: I dont know anything about the internals but is the loot generated when the chunk is created or upon opening (or destroying) it the first time?

Comment: @Gigala It's generated when opening/destroying. When the chunk is created, the chest with the dormant loot table is placed.

Comment: thanks for the info, thats interesting and good to know :) Edit: to clarify: the loot is already determined when the chunk is generated but the actual content of the chest isnt, right?

Comment: @Gigala That's correct, the chest will be empty until interacted with. For NBT data, it will have a `LootTable` string containing the name of the loot table, as well as a `LootTableSeed` tag that will help determine what loot is obtained from the table (so that the same world seed results in the same loot). The `Items` list will be empty. Example NBT that a chest would have in that scenario: `{LootTable:"minecraft:chests/simple_dungeon",LootTableSeed:1,Items:[]}`

Comment: Ok mate, I understand how it works now, thank you.

Comment: @Skylinerw but only in new versions, where loot tables are, right? Old versions will generate loot when chunk is generated, hm?

Comment: @AntoineHejlík That is correct.

Answer (score -2):

Wait it out, dungeons have good loot. Make a path up to surface and try to loot resources from the area. I once destroyed a chest that I hadn't looted yet and got nothing later. If the items come they will most likely despawn unless you afk there.

Comment: This does not answer the question and is instead giving unrelated advice. The asker is looking for technical details about the loot generation mechanic involving the new [loot tables feature](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Loot_table) introduced in 1.9 (in which a chest does not contain loot until interacted with, and a player in spectator mode is not allowed to check the chest as demonstrated in the image in the OP).